# How to make a table visible in Hue?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, impala, cloudera-cdh, hue

In Hue, I am not able to see the table. Although the table's data can be seen at the backend in the linux box. Tried refreshing the data, but, which didn't work.
Please let me know what needs to be done.

Thanks,
MMB

Comment: Please add more details about the environment.

Comment: Most likely, you need to `INVALIDATE METADATA` for this table. https://impala.apache.org/docs/build/html/topics/impala_invalidate_metadata.html

Comment: refresh table tablename and invalidate metadata on the impala editor should update the tablelist.